# Showing Icons for hidden Actionbar items

Tags: android

I have an **actionabar** and I have hidden some of its items by:

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

So these Items appear in the **three dots** area (the popup menu) . But then the icons won't be shown.
I thought these is the common behavior in android and you cannot show any icons in the **three dots** area. But then I saw a sample where android itself uses items in this area, but all have icons.
For example some apps have a **Share** item in the three dots area and if you click on it, some apps (like facebook, twitter etc.) appear in the popu menu and all of them have icons.
How can I show items in the **three dots** area (in the popup menu) that have icons or images?

Comment: Share is under three dots without icon. And if you click on share - you will see the list with icons. "Share" is actionbar item, and it can open popup with custom layout, but popup under three dots is actionbar popup. So, you can't add icons there. Workaround is to create "three dots" button manually, make it dropdown, and use custom layout for that dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **actionbarsherlock** to achieve the same.

### make sure you extends **SherlockActivity**.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

         MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();  
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

            SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu(0, 0, 2, "ITEM");

            subMenu.add(0, 2, 2, "ITEM1")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ur_icon);

            subMenu.add(0, 3, 3, "ITEM2")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ur_icon);

            MenuItem subMenuItem = subMenu.getItem();
            subMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_dark);
            subMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```